# Find the indefinite integral $\int (a+x)^{2 \over 3} x^3 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the indefinite integral

$$\int (a+x)^{2 \over 3} x^3 dx$$

any hints?

Comment: integration by parts, but it leads me to nowhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice, let $a+x=t\implies dx=dt$ 
$$\int (a+x)^{2/3}x^3\ dx=\int t^{2/3}(t-a)^3\ dt$$
$$=\int t^{2/3}(t^3-3at^2+3a^2t-a^3)\ dt$$
$$=\int (t^{11/3}-3at^{8/3}+3a^2t^{5/3}-a^3t^{2/3})\ dt$$
$$=\int t^{11/3}\ dt-3a\int t^{8/3}\ dt+3a^2\int t^{5/3}\ dt-a^3\int t^{2/3}\ dt$$